# אין קטיגור נעשה סניגור

Tags: talmud-gemara, rosh-hashanah-new-year

So this concept in the title we use in numerous places, most notably the Gemara in Rosh Hashanah which says that you can’t blow the horn of a cow because it will remind Hashem of chet haegel (and this fits in with the concept of ein kategor). So my question is applying this to modern things, specifically a phone. Can a phone that has been used for bad or inappropriate things be used as a siddur to pray to Hashem, or does this violate the concept of ein kategor?

Comment: What evidence do you have that this principle should be applied outside of Hazalic legislation? We do not, for example, make up new applications of a גזירה שוה... what makes you think this is any different?

Comment: Does this principle ever apply to specific things and not categories (cow horns vs Bessie's horns)

Comment: I am shocked that no one mentioned the following yerushalmi https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Berakhot.1.2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gemara [Rosh Hashana 26A](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.26a.7-11?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi) explains that this rule only applies in extremely specific situations;

> עוּלָּא אָמַר: הַיְינוּ טַעְמָא דְּרַבָּנַן, כִּדְרַב חִסְדָּא. דְּאָמַר רַב חִסְדָּא: מִפְּנֵי מָה אֵין כֹּהֵן גָּדוֹל נִכְנָס בְּבִגְדֵי זָהָב לִפְנַי וְלִפְנִים לַעֲבוֹד עֲבוֹדָה — לְפִי שֶׁאֵין קָטֵיגוֹר נַעֲשָׂה סָנֵיגוֹר

> Ulla said: This is the reasoning of the Rabbis, who say that the horn of a cow is unfit for sounding on Rosh HaShana. They say this in accordance with the opinion of Rav Ḥisda, as Rav Ḥisda said: For what reason does the High Priest not enter the innermost sanctum, the Holy of Holies, with his golden garments to perform the service there on Yom Kippur? It is because a prosecutor [kateigor] cannot become an advocate [sanneigor]. Since the Jewish people committed the sin of worshipping the Golden Calf, the High Priest may not enter the Holy of Holies to atone for the Jewish people wearing golden garments, as they would bring that sin to mind.

> וְלָא? וְהָא אִיכָּא דָּם פַּר! הוֹאִיל וְאִשְׁתַּנִּי — אִשְׁתַּנִּי.

> The Gemara asks: But do we not use a cow in the Holy of Holies? But there is the blood of the bull that is brought there to be sprinkled on Yom Kippur, despite the fact that the Jewish people sinned with a calf. The Gemara answers: Since it has changed, i.e., it is not the bull itself, but only its blood, then it has changed, i.e., so it does not bring the sin of the Golden Calf to mind.

> וְהָא אִיכָּא אָרוֹן וְכַפּוֹרֶת וּכְרוּב! חוֹטֵא בַּל יַקְרִיב קָאָמְרִינַן.

> The Gemara raises another difficulty: But there is the Ark, the Ark cover, and the cherub, all of which are plated with gold. If this is problematic, why are they in the Holy of Holies? The Gemara explains: What we are saying is that a sinner seeking atonement should not bring something made of gold into the Holy of Holies, as it would bring the sin of the Golden Calf to mind.

> וְהָא אִיכָּא כַּף וּמַחְתָּה! חוֹטֵא בַּל יִתְנָאֶה קָא אָמְרִינַן.

> The Gemara asks further: But there is the spoon and coal pan that are brought into the Holy of Holies, and they are made of gold. The Gemara answers: What we are saying is that a sinner seeking atonement should not adorn himself with ornaments of gold.

> וְהָא אִיכָּא בִּגְדֵי זָהָב מִבַּחוּץ! מִבִּפְנִים קָא אָמְרִינַן. שׁוֹפָר נָמֵי מִבַּחוּץ הוּא! כֵּיוָן דִּלְזִכָּרוֹן הוּא — כְּבִפְנִים דָּמֵי.

> The Gemara raises yet another question: But there are the golden garments the High Priest wears outside the Holy of Holies. The Gemara answers: What we are saying is that a sinner should not adorn himself with gold inside the Holy of Holies, but outside there is no concern. The Gemara continues this line of questioning: If so, the shofar is also outside, since it is not brought into the Holy of Holies. The Gemara answers: Since the shofar is sounded in order to evoke God’s remembrance, it is considered as if it were sounded inside the Holy of Holies.

So in essence it only applies to the one who is doing the Kapparah in the Kodesh Kodshim who is making himself nice with the object. A phone obviously would not qualify as such.

Comment: I don't see how this proves your assertion. There are other cases where this phrase arises (lulabh hagazul, a kohen that murdered not saying birkhath kohanim, etc.). Clearly the principle was applied by Hazal in other instances. OP seems to want to know whether we may apply the principle, and if so, what are the criteria for its application. And if not, then why not.

Comment: Can you provide a specific case? The answer I gave is a quote from the Gemara RH that the OP quoted. All the commentaries explain the fact that Aharon Hakohen brought  an egel by the hakamas hamishkan to atone for the egel, as rashi says, by saying that since it wasn’t brought in the K”K it is not an issue, based on this Gemara. If you have a case that is a question, then post it as a question on the Gemara RH. The two cases you mentioned are irrelevant. Lulav is Mitzvah habah baveira which is a different concept entirely, and Birchas kohanim the Gemara berachos 32B uses a different passuk

Comment: In fact, from the fact that the Gemara in these 2 instances that you quoted, specifically doesn’t mention kateigar, it is apparent that this concept doesn’t apply there

Comment: Milhamoth Hashem (of Ramban) on Pereq Lulabh ha-Gazul, Tosafoth 7a DH sheneamar, Sefer Hasidim 149, for starters. Clearly the principle is applied elsewhere. RH 26a does not state about the principle what you claim it does. I'm not saying we can/ought willy-nilly apply it elsewhere, but that it is applied elsewhere is evident (and thus serves to prompt the question as to what are the guidelines for its application).

Comment: They use it as halachic principle or just a borrowed phrase?

Comment: Check inside and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

'אין קטיגור נעשה סניגור' isn't an issur, saying that it can't be, its a klal, saying that it isn't. Its not something that can be violated, rather its a metzius, a reality. So the ramifications of 'אין קטיגור נעשה סניגור' in your case wouldn't be that you transgressed something, it would (hypothetically) be that your tefillos would have less power.

In regards to whether using a phone that is used for inappropriate things would affect the power of your tefillos, assuming using your phone won't distract you and have you thinking about this question, and ignoring the fact that if someone has a phone that they are using for innapropriate things they should get it filtered/get rid of it, I wouldn't think so - the קטיגור, in this case the phone, isn't the סניגור - the סניגור is your tefillos, you davening (as opposed to the סניגור being you phone).

Comment: Get one of the artscroll pocket-sized mincha/maariv interlinear siddurim, by the way - whether this is a hypothetical question or not, they are great.